# Jags RUNTIME ERROR: Compilation error on line 17. Attempt to redefine node delta[15,1,1]

Tags: compiler-errors, runtime-error, jags, rjags

I am having a problem to compile a Jags model using the following code. It seems that the parameter delta is being tried to be redefined (line 17 : delta[i, si[i, k], hh] ~ dnorm(md[i, si[i, k], hh], taud[i, si[i, k], hh])) at the beginning of the third loop within the model, but I am unsure why?

The model is:

```
        model
{
    for (hh in 1:nrepeat) {
        for (i in 1:ns) {
            w[i, 1, hh] <- 0.00000E+00
            j[i, 1, hh] <- 0.00000E+00
            delta[i, bi[i, hh], hh] <- 0.00000E+00
            mu[i, hh] ~ dnorm(0.00000E+00, 1.00000E-05)
            beta0[i, hh] ~ dnorm(0.00000E+00, 1.00000E-05)
            b1[i, 1, hh] <- 0.00000E+00
            for (k in 1:na[i]) {
                index[i, k, hh] <- split[i, hh] * (equals(t[i, 
                  k], pair[hh, 1]) + equals(t[i, k], pair[hh, 
                  2]))
            }
            for (k in 2:na[i]) {
                delta[i, si[i, k], hh] ~ dnorm(md[i, si[i, k], 
                  hh], taud[i, si[i, k], hh])
                md[i, si[i, k], hh] <- (d[si[i, k], hh] - d[bi[i, 
                  hh], hh] + sw[i, k, hh] + b1[i, k, hh]) * (1 - 
                  index[i, m[i, k], hh]) + direct[hh] * index[i, 
                  m[i, k], hh]
                j[i, k, hh] <- k - (equals(1, split[i, hh]) * 
                  step(k - 3))
                taud[i, si[i, k], hh] <- tau[hh] * 2 * (j[i, 
                  k, hh] - 1)/j[i, k, hh]
                w[i, k, hh] <- (delta[i, si[i, k], hh] - ((d[si[i, 
                  k], hh] - d[bi[i, hh], hh]) + b1[i, k, hh])) * 
                  (1 - index[i, k, hh])
                sw[i, k, hh] <- sum(w[i, 1:(k - 1), hh])/(j[i, 
                  k, hh] - 1)
                b1[i, k, hh] <- (beta[t[i, k], hh] * (x[i] - 
                  mx))
            }
        }
        for (l in 1:np) {
            r[l] ~ dbin(p[l], n[l])
            logit(p[l]) <- mu[s[l], hh] + beta0[s[l], hh] * (x[l] - 
                mx) + delta[s[l], tipd[l], hh] + (deltab[l, hh] * 
                (1 - equals(tipd[l], bi[s[l], hh])))
            rhat[l] <- p[l] * n[l]
            dev[l] <- 2 * (r[l] * (log(r[l]) - log(rhat[l])) + 
                (n[l] - r[l]) * (log(n[l] - r[l]) - log(n[l] - 
                  rhat[l])))
            index2[l, hh] <- split[s[l], hh] * (equals(tipd[l], 
                pair[hh, 1]) + equals(tipd[l], pair[hh, 2]))
            deltab[l, hh] <- (beta[tipd[l], hh] - beta[bi[s[l], 
                hh], hh]) * (x[l] - mx) * (1 - index2[l, hh]) + 
                directbeta[hh] * (x[l] - mx) * (index2[l, hh])
        }
        totresdev[hh] <- sum(dev[])
        direct[hh] ~ dnorm(0.00000E+00, 1.00000E-05)
        directbeta[hh] ~ dnorm(0.00000E+00, 1.00000E-05)
        d[1, hh] <- 0.00000E+00
        beta[1, hh] <- 0.00000E+00
        sd[hh] ~ dunif(0.00000E+00, 10)
        tau[hh] <- pow(sd[hh], -2)
        tausq[hh] <- sd[hh] * sd[hh]
        for (k in 2:nt) {
            d[k, hh] ~ dnorm(0.00000E+00, 1.00000E-05)
            beta[k, hh] ~ dnorm(0.00000E+00, 1.00000E-05)
        }
        for (k in 1:nt) {
            for (v in 1:nz) {
                dz[v, k, hh] <- d[k, hh] - (beta[k, hh]) * (mx - 
                  z[v])
            }
        }
        for (c in 1:(nt - 1)) {
            for (k in (c + 1):nt) {
                betas[c, k, hh] <- beta[k, hh] - beta[c, hh]
                lor[c, k, hh] <- (d[k, hh] - d[c, hh])
                for (v in 1:nz) {
                  lorz[v, c, k] <- (dz[v, k, hh] - dz[v, c, hh])
                }
            }
        }
        for (v in 1:nz) {
            directz[v, hh] <- direct[hh] - (directbeta[hh]) * 
                (mx - z[v])
            directorz[v, hh] <- exp(directz[v, hh])
        }
        for (v in 1:nz) {
            diff[v, hh] <- directz[v, hh] - lorz[v, pair[hh, 
                1], pair[hh, 2]]
            prob[v, hh] <- step(diff[v, hh])
        }
    }
}
```

Data file can be obtained here:
[data and model file](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/baizo8l4h5wv8ph/AABU69UBtrU5m6W9zBTVNc25a?dl=0)

Input for JAGS:

```
rm(list = ls())
library(coda)
library(rjags)
library(netmeta);

#LOAD FUNCTIONS TO SHAPE DATA
#CHECK IF PAIR(X,Y) IN ROW I OF DATA AND GIVE BASELINE FOR DATA ROW I
PairXY <- function(treat, pair)
{
  N <- nrow(treat)
  out <- cbind(split=rep(0,N), b=rep(0,N))
  for (i in 1:N) {
    pos <- match(pair, treat[i,], nomatch=0) # lenght = length(pair) = 2
    out[i,1] <- ifelse(prod(pos)>0, 1, 0) # 1 if pair in line i, 0 o.w.
    out[i,2] <- ifelse(prod(pos)==0, 1, pos[1])
  }
  out
}
# GIVES NA-1 INDEXES TO SWEEP NON-BASELINE ARMS ONLY
NonbaseSweep <- function(index, na)
{
  N <- NROW(na)
  C <- max(na)
  out <- matrix(nrow=N, ncol=C)
  for (i in 1:N) {
    for (k in 2:na[i]) {
      out[i,k] <- k - (index[i,"b"] >= k)


    }
  }
  out
}
# BUILDS MATRIX WITH NON-BASELINE TREATMENTS
Sweeptreat <- function(treat, m)
{
  N <- NROW(treat)
  C <- NCOL(m)
  out <- matrix(nrow=N, ncol=C)
  for (i in 1:N) {
    for (k in 2:C) {
      out[i,k] <- treat[i,m[i,k]]
    }
  }
  out
}
## BUILDS VECTOR WITH BASELINE TREATMENTS
Basetreat <- function(treat, b)
{
  N <- nrow(treat)
  out <- rep(0,N)
  for (i in 1:N) {
    out[i] <- treat[i,b[i]]
  }
  out
}

# Data
datasrc <- read.csv('OR_Responders.csv', header=TRUE)
datasrc[] <- lapply(datasrc, function(x){
  x[is.nan(x)] <- NA
  x
}) 
datasrc<-subset(datasrc,datasrc$XSev1!="NA")

mx<-mean(c(datasrc$XSev1,datasrc$XSev2,datasrc$XSev3),na.rm = TRUE); 
dat1<-datasrc
dat1$study<-1:length(dat1$t1)
dat2 <- pairwise(list(t1, t2, t3),event=list(r1,r2,r3),n=list(n1, n2, n3),data=dat1, studlab=study)

na=dat1$na #NUMBER OF ARMS IN EACH STUDY
t=cbind(dat1$t1,dat1$t2,dat1$t3, deparse.level = 0) #TREATMENT NUMBER
s=dat2$studlab #STUDY NUMBER
#y=dat2$TE #OUTCOME
r=dat2$event1+dat2$event2
n=dat2$n1+dat2$n2
tipd=dat2$treat2 #TREATMENT NUMBER
x=dat2$XSevag #COVARIATE VALUES
#x=dat2$age/12 #COVARIATE VALUES
ns=max(s) #NMUBER OF TRIALS
nt=22 #NUMBER OF TREATMENTS
np=length(x) #NUMBER OF PATIENTS
mx=mean(x) #AVERAGE COVARIATE VALUE
z=c(10,20,30,40,50) #CHOSEN COVARIATE VALUES AT WHICH TREATMENT EFFECTS ARE REQUIRED TO BE ESTIMATED.
nz=length(z) #NUMBER OF CHOSEN COVARIATE VALUES


#CHOOSE NODE TO SPLIT
parameters = c("prob","diff");model.file1 = "ModelC1.txt"
contre <- read.csv('Treat.csv', header=TRUE)

pair<-contre[,2:3];pair<-data.matrix(pair, rownames.force = NA)
split <- array(0, dim=c(ns,length(contre[,1])))
bi <- array(0, dim=c(ns,length(contre[,1])))


for (i in 1:length(contre[,1])) {
  pairx <- c(contre[i,2],contre[i,3]);
  checkPair <- PairXY(t, pairx);split[,i]<-checkPair[,"split"]
  bix <- Basetreat(t, checkPair[,"b"]);bi[,i] = bix;
  m <- NonbaseSweep(checkPair, na);#m[,i] = mtt;
  si <- Sweeptreat(t,m);#si[,i] = six;
}

# Defining some MCMC parameters for JAGS
nchains  <- 3; # How Many Chains?
nadapt<-100
nburnin  <- 100; # How Many Burn-in Samples?
nsamples <- 100;  # How Many Recorded Samples?
nthin <- 10;

datastruct<-list(z=z, nz=nz,ns=ns,nt=nt,mx=mx,s=s,na=na,nrepeat=length(pair[,1]),split = split,m=m,bi=bi,si=si,pair=pair,x=x,tipd=tipd,t=t,r=r,n=n,np=np)
mod1 <- jags.model(file =model.file1, data=datastruct, n.chains=nchains, n.adapt=nadapt);
# update(mod1, nburnin);
# sim<-coda.samples(mod1, parameters, nsamples, thin = nthin, na.rm=TRUE);
# simsum<-summary(sim);
```

The error message is:

```
Compiling model graph
   Resolving undeclared variables
   Allocating nodes
Deleting model

Error in jags.model(file = model.file1, data = datastruct, n.chains = nchains,  : 
  RUNTIME ERROR:
Compilation error on line 17.
Attempt to redefine node delta[15,1,1]
```

Any hint would be very much appreciated. 
Thanks
Liso

Comment: It is difficult to answer your question as your code is not reproducible: we don't have access to your data. But at a guess: are all si[i, k] unique? If not (i.e. two values of si share the same value for different i,k) then this would cause the error you are seeing. Otherwise please make your code reproducible so that we can answer your question.

Comment: Thank you very much, I added the data files. The node-splitting model aims to loop over several pairs of treatment comparisons in order to avoid running the node-splitting model once for each treatment comparison (which is very time consuming). The original code works fine when running the model without that additional loop. Code for the original model can also be obtained in the link.